# How to calculate walking distance between multiple addresses? - QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, google-maps, historical-maps

I am working with historical data and I would like to calculate the walking distance between multiple addresses. For instance, in my excel dataset I have someone who lived on 1 Laurierstraat in Amsterdam and went to the pub on 10 Rozengracht, Amsterdam. I have hundred of cases like that, combining the source and the destination. Is there an easy way (for someone with no programming knowledge) to import these data and calculate the walking distance for each set?

Comment: Grass in QGIS can do routing. If you have possible paths they could have taken you can get a route and get distance. You will need paths they could potentially take though... ie roads or sidewalks as a layer.

Comment: There are, at least now, QGIX native network (routing) algorithms that can achieve that.